# eMMC vs MMC communication protocol

Tags: memory, storage, sd-card, mmc

I am trying to communicate with an eMMC flash memory. I already have a library for connecting to MMC flash memory which is based on SPI protocol. In new eMMCs SPI protocol is not supported. I want to ask is the protocol in MMC different to eMMC fundamentally? To be more clear can I just send and receive the same data which was send in SPI mode just in parall to eMMC to get the same result?

Thanks

Answer (score 1):

eMMC and MMC are largely interchangeable. However, eMMC and latterly MMC no longer support SPI. If you solder eMMC to a board and plug it into a card reader it will work just like an SDCard. However, the protocol is native to MMC and SPI won't work.